# Nuxt 3 - Plugin initialization after Api Response

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am using Nuxt 3 and need a third-party SearchClient on many Components in my Application.
I want to provide this Client via a plugin in the application.

However, the client needs an ApiKey for initialization and this cannot be changed afterwards.
But I will get this ApiKey later. Not when loading the Nuxt 3 application,

Is there a possibility to initialize the plugin later?

Here how I plan to do it:

Plugin:

```
interface ISearchClientInstance {
  directClient: Client;
  customer: CustomerSearchModule;
  product: ...;
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig();

  const client: Client = new Client({
    nodes: [
      {
        host: config.public.typesense_host as string,
        port: config.public.typesense_port as number,
        protocol: config.public.typesense_protocol as string
      }
    ],
    apiKey: // Here I need an apiKey from an Api-Call
  });

  const modules: ISearchClientInstance = {
    directClient: client,
    customer: new CustomerSearchClient(client),
    product: ...;
  };

  return {
    provide: {
      searchApi: modules
    }
  };
});
```

```
export default class CustomerSearchModule extends SearchFactory {
  private client: Client;

  constructor(client: Client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  async search(): Customer {
    // a predefined search for customers
  }
}
```

I'm getting the apiKey in an composable with other data:

```
    const wrapper: UserDataWrapper = await cxt.$api.user.getUserInfo(fbUid);
    const user: AppUser = wrapper.user;
    const searchApiKey: string = wrapper.searchApiKey;
    ...
    ...
```

Does what I have in mind make any sense at all, or should I take a completely different approach?

I tried to find a Solution but didn't find an approach.
First i tried to change the Configuration of the Typesense Client. But this is not possible.
Perhaps there is a way to reinitialize the client in the plugin?

Comment: Why is there necessity to create Client instance in defineNuxtPlugin? This could be done later, as long as you wait for it to be initialized. Also plugin setup can be async

Comment: How can i do that? Nuxt3 loads the plugin automatically at the creation of the application.